# Increment number in array formula based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a data set with Sub-Total rows at various intervals. As the data can have rows inserted or deleted, I am trying to use an array formula to give each group of data an incremented integer as a reference number.

Example Data:

```
Column A:  
x  
x  
Sub-Total  
x  
x  
x  
Sub-Total
```

When using a filled-down formula I can place '1' in B1, then `=if(A1="Sub-Total",B1+1,B1)` in cells B2 and down. This yields the following in column B:

```
1  
1  
1  
2  
2  
2  
2
```

I have tried:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A1:A="Sub-Total",B1:B+1,B1:B))
```

But the `FALSE` condition does not seem to reference the row above and shows as blank.

I have also tried using `OFFSET()`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

- for "sub-total" count you can use:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="Sub-Total", COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), ))
  ```

  [image: 0]